# Longest path in a grid

Tags: combinatorics

I recently saw a computer programming question that asked for the longest path that one can build in a $3\times3$ unit grid connecting the vertexes, with the following rules(the same rules of a pattern password):

- Each vertex may be used at most once.
- A vertex cannot be skipped in a line if it is not used previously.
- If a vertex is used then it must be skipped if a line crosses it.

Now, since $9!=362880$ the problem is trivial by bruteforce. But, is there an analytical way of solving the problem?

Comment: Can the paths travel diagonally?

Comment: @ozo Yeah, no problem!

Comment: In either case, this problem is NP-hard: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X11003088

Comment: Although they mention that there are some special cases that can be solved in polynomial time; if I may hijack this thread, does anyone know what these cases are?

Comment: @ozo I am not claiming that the list is exhaustive, but [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Special_classes_of_graphs) seems to answer your question. And thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to start with longest distances and then add shorter.
You have the following vertex sequence

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & \cdots & 6 & \cdots & 9 & \cdots & 3 \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
10 & \cdots & 13 & \cdots & 16 & \cdots & 8 \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
4 & \cdots & 15 & \cdots & 14 & \cdots & 12 \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
7 & \cdots & 11 & \cdots & 2 & \cdots & 5 \\
\end{array}
$$

And we obtain the distance

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
1 & [\sqrt{13}] & 2 & [\sqrt{10}] &
3 & [\sqrt{13}] & 2 & [\sqrt{10}] &
5 & [\sqrt{13}] & 6 & [\sqrt{10}] &
7 & [\sqrt{13}] & 8
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
8 & [\sqrt{2}] &
9 & [\sqrt{5}] &
10 & [\sqrt{5}] &
11 & [\sqrt{5}] &
12 & [\sqrt{5}] &
13
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
13 & [\sqrt{2}] &
14 & [1] &
15 & [\sqrt{2}] &
16
\end{array},\\
$$

(if I did understood the rules...)

---

Totaly

$$
1 + 3 \sqrt{2} + 4 \sqrt{5} + 3 \sqrt{10} + 4 \sqrt{13},
$$

or

$$
38.09595...
$$